# dynamic 2d matrix implementation

Tags: c

insdead of my static matrix i try to get 2d dynamic matrics
all i want to do is to change the init function so instead of using the defined heigh and width
it would init dynamicaly - please show me the how

```
void init(int board[][WIDTH], int rows) {
    int x, y;
    for (y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            board[y][x] = 0;
    /* Scatter some live cells: */
    board[10][25] = 1;
    board[10][26] = 1;
    board[10][27] = 1;
    board[11][25] = 1;
    board[12][26] = 1;
}

int main(void) {  
    int board[HEIGHT][WIDTH];  
    init(board, HEIGHT);  
..
..
}
```

this is the code i wanted to use - please show me the right implamintation
without using     `#define WIDTH 50` #define HEIGHT 20

```
    int **matrix_dyn(int n, int m)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

            printf ("please enter the horizontal size of the board \n");
        scanf ("%d", &n);

        printf ("please enter the vertical size of the board \n");
        scanf ("%d", &m);


        int **board = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));

        printf("please enter the 0's or 1's to fill the matrix \n");
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        board[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));

        for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j <= m; j++)
            scanf ("%d", &board[i][j]);
        }
        return board;
    }
```

this is all my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define WIDTH 50
    #define HEIGHT 20

    void init(int board[][WIDTH], int rows) {
        int x, y;
        for (y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
                board[y][x] = 0;
        /* Scatter some live cells: */
        board[10][25] = 1;
        board[10][26] = 1;
        board[10][27] = 1;
        board[11][25] = 1;
        board[12][26] = 1;
    }


    void print(int board[][WIDTH], int rows, int cols) 

    {
        int x, y;
        char c;
        for (y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
             if (board[y][x] == 1)
                    printf("X");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("Press any key to continue:\n");
        getchar();
    }


    int count_neighbors(int board[][WIDTH], int rows, 
            int y, int x)
    {
        int i, j;
        int result = 0;
        for (i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            if ((y+i >= 0) && (y+i < rows))
                for (j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                    if ((x+j >= 0) && (x+j < WIDTH))
                        if ((i != 0) || (j != 0))
                            result += board[y+i][x+j];
        return result;
    }



    int step(int board[][WIDTH], int rows) { // now returns a bool
        int x, y; 
        int neighbors[HEIGHT][WIDTH]; 
        int changed = 0; // save changes
        for (y = 0; y < rows; y++) 
            for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) 
                neighbors[y][x] = count_neighbors(board, rows, y, x); 
        for (y = 0; y < rows; y++) 
            for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) 
                if (board[y][x] == 1) { /* Currently alive */ 
                    if (neighbors[y][x] < 2) 
                    {
                        board[y][x] = 0; /* Death by boredom */ 
                        changed = 1; // change happened
                    }
                    else if (neighbors[y][x] > 3) 
                    {
                        board[y][x] = 0; /* Death by overcrowding */ 
                        changed = 1; // change happened
                    }
                } 
                else { /* Currently empty */ 
                    if (neighbors[y][x] == 3) 
                    {
                        board[y][x] = 1; 
                        changed = 1; // change happened
                    }
                } 
        return changed; // return the status (changed yes/no?)
    } 


    int main(void) {  
        int board[HEIGHT][WIDTH];  
        init(board, HEIGHT);  
        while (1) {  
            print(board, HEIGHT, WIDTH);
            if(step(board, HEIGHT) == 0) // no change
                break; // leave the loop
        }  
        return 0;  
    }
```

Comment: You're posting question after question about mostly the same issues with the same code. You should take the time to site down and read a good C bool to _understand_ pointers and arrays. Getting spoon-fed every little syntax detail isn't going to help you in the long run if you don't understand what you're doing and why you need to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Declare & allocate board like so:

```
int *board = malloc( n * m * sizeof(int) );
```

Then, anytime you wish to access board[x][y], use the following expression:

```
board[y*n+x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a struct, heres a simple implementation I wrote up (compiled using GCC, to support the `constructor` attribute.

```
// IntGrid.h
typedef struct intGrid_t {
    int **data;
    int rows;
    int cols;
} *IntGridRef;

struct {
    IntGridRef(* create)(int, int);
    void  (* print)(IntGridRef);
    void  (* free)(IntGridRef);
    int **(* data)(IntGridRef);
    int   (* rows)(IntGridRef);
    int   (* cols)(IntGridRef);
} IntGrid;

// IntGrid.c
IntGridRef _intGrid_create(int rows, int cols);
void _intGrid_print(IntGridRef this);
void _intGrid_free(IntGridRef this);
int **_intGrid_data(IntGridRef this);
int _intGrid_rows(IntGridRef this);
int _intGrid_cols(IntGridRef this);

__attribute__((constructor))
static void intGrid_setup()
{
    IntGrid.create = _intGrid_create;
    IntGrid.print = _intGrid_print;
    IntGrid.free = _intGrid_free;
    IntGrid.data = _intGrid_data;
    IntGrid.rows = _intGrid_rows;
    IntGrid.cols = _intGrid_cols;
}

IntGridRef _intGrid_create(int rows, int cols)
{
    IntGridRef this = calloc(1, sizeof(struct intGrid_t));
    this->rows = rows;
    this->cols = cols;
    this->data = calloc(rows, sizeof(int *));

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        this->data[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof(int *));
    }

    return this;
}

void _intGrid_print(IntGridRef this)
{
    printf("{\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++) {
        printf(" { ");
        for (int j = 0; j < this->cols; j++) {
            printf("%i", this->data[i][j]);

            if (j != this->cols - 1)
            {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
        printf(" }\n");
    }
    printf("}\n");
}
void _intGrid_free(IntGridRef this)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++) {
        free(this->data[i]);
    }

    free(this->data);
    free(this);
}
int **_intGrid_data(IntGridRef this)
{
    return this->data;
}
int _intGrid_rows(IntGridRef this)
{
    return this->rows;
}
int _intGrid_cols(IntGridRef this)
{
    return this->cols;
}
```

Example Usage:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    IntGridRef grid = IntGrid.create(10, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < IntGrid.rows(grid); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < IntGrid.cols(grid); j++) {
            IntGrid.data(grid)[i][j] = arc4random_uniform(10);
        }
    }

    IntGrid.print(grid);
    IntGrid.free(grid);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain it in c syntax? please look at my code - all i ask is how to implement my dynamic code into my all code program

Comment: My Code is In C, I simply use a struct with function pointers to give the appearance of a class, if you were to copy/paste this into your application it would most likely work.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically there, but instead of having the compiler generate code to map [x][y] to a specific element in the memory allocated for board, you have to do the mapping yourself: board[x*h+y] or board[y*w+x] (where w is width & h is height); it doesn't matter which you choose, just be consistent (a function or macro would help here).